# Overloading method with generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have method that returns generic parameter. 
For example

```
public E doSmth(E item){
return item;
}
```

Is there a way to create same method get but only for example String like

```
public String doSmth(String item){
return item + item;
}
```

So if i pass String, it works with String, but if i pass anything else it does basic method with generic. Can i somehow do it without error that 'two same methods in class' ?

Comment: A way around this issue is to have the generic method more complicated, having it delegate work based on the type of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This should work right? Java will always try to call the method that has the most refined type of the parameter you have put in the call

```
public <E> E doSmth(E item){
  return item;
}


public String doSmth(String item){
 return item + item;
}
```

Comment: No. It won't work. Compiler will say "i have two exact same methods and don't know wich one to use"

Comment: Can you show how you call the method? I tried this multiple times and it seems to work. Do you have other method with the same signature that might conflict?